# How do I convert values like this to date type in R?

Tags: r, datetime-format, date-conversion

I have a data frame with a "date" (factor with different levels) column with values like  X3.5.20, x3.6.20, x3.7.20, and so on. This is in the format (month.date.year).

My question is how can I convert this to a date variable in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R does not let the column names to start with numbers by default hence `'X'` is added at the beginning, however, you can avoid that by using `check.names = FALSE` when importing the dataframe. If you have csv named `data.csv`, you can do

```
df <- read.csv('data.csv', check.names = FALSE)
```

---

If you have already imported the data you can change the column names by

```
names(df) <- as.Date(names(df), 'X%m.%d.%y')
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `read_csv` from `readr`

```
library(readr)
df <- read_csv('data.csv')
```